# MVC5 runtime error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I am about to lose my mind here because the following makes absolutely no sense whatsoever.

Here is my _Layout.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
        @RenderBody()
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my Controller:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<ActionResult> Show(string id)
{
    var a = new TournamentViewModel();
    a.IsAdmin = true;
    return View(a);
}
```

Here is my View

```
@using System.Threading
@using System.Web.Mvc.Html
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity
@model MyProj.Models.ViewModels.TournamentViewModel
@if (@Model != null)
{
    var adminUser = @Model.IsAdmin;
    if (adminUser)
    {

    } 
}
```

Here is the error

> Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 
>   Compiler Error Message: CS1513: } expected
>   Source Error:
>
> Line 81:         }
>   Line 82:     }
>   Line 83: }

Here is what I tried:

On my view if I change `var adminUser = @Model.IsAdmin;` to `var adminUser =true` then this works without problems.

If I remove the following code

```
if (adminUser)
{

}
```

then it works without problems.

I don't get it, there are no syntax errors anywhere.  And another thing I don't get is that I emptied out my _Layout.cshtml but yet its failing on line 83, not sure where it is getting those extra html lines from.

Comment: In a view, you use `@Model` from within html blocks. From within already started code blocks you use just `Model`. Also you are not returning anything from your `Show()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are writing `@Model` instead of `Model` in the if loop. Try removing `@` and you should be fine.